# react-native-linear-gradient, Cannot find module 'react-native-linear-gradient' or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: typescript, react-native

Using RN And typescript, when I try and install, `react-native-linear-gradient`, I get the above error and the package doesn't install.

How can I use the package in my app?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with yarn?
`yarn add react-native-linear-gradient`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your package.json

```js
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
```

And then run npm install after that run your code with **"npx react-native run-android**"